# Play2 with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, playframework-2.0

I am now very far in my project ~around 60 different views and I all wrote them without IDE support.

Now I really want to use the scala IDE in eclipse

I tried it with eclipse helios indigo and juno with the same result

I followed this tutorial http://scala-ide.org/docs/tutorials/play20scalaide20/index.html

Now I think that there is a small mistake in this tutorial
[image]

He chose the mainfolder but I think the src_managed folder is the correct one. However I tried both without any success.

My eclipse looks like this

[image]

I tried `play clean` and `play compile` `play run` and `play ~run`.

- I just want to have scala support in .scala.html is this currently possible?
- If yes is there a solution where I can format my .scala.html file?

Comment: FYI: future version of Intellij - Leda: http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/06/intellij-idea-12-leda-preview-is-out/ - has support for Play's 2.0 templates, routes etc, via plugin: http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin?pr=idea&pluginId=7080&showAllUpdates=true

Comment: I tested it one or two months ago and the html formatting destroyed all my scala.html files. Do you know if it's possible to format those?

Comment: Probably you tested current stable Idea (11.x) and yes, most probably formatting command damages views, anyway I just tested versions from links (Leda+plugin) minutes ago, and I'm impressed, it formats and validates views almost ideally. There are small issues with formatting, anyway I think it's should be tested by us (Players) and sent to JetBrain bugtracker

Comment: Yeah you are right it works pretty descent. however you have to put variables in parentheses @(content) to get the autocompletion, but it is not a big deal.

Comment: This plugin is very fresh, I assume it needs tweaking still.